# EJB Annotation and Interface

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, ejb

I'm starting to study EJB, and i'm having problems deploying my application.

I'm using JBoss as Application Server.

This is my Bean Interface:

```
public interface HelloWorldInterface {

    public String printMessage();
}
```

---

This is my Bean (local):

```
@Local
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class LocalHelloWorld implements HelloWorldInterface{

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public LocalHelloWorld() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public String printMessage() {

        return "This is a local EJB called \"LocalHelloWorld\"";
    }
}
```

---

This is my servlet using it:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private LocalHelloWorld localHelloWorld;
}
```

---

I get this error:

> Caused by:
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   WFLYEJB0406: No EJB found with interface of type
>   'source.bean.LocalHelloWorld' for binding MyServlet/localHelloWorld
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource.getResourceValue(EjbInjectionSource.java:90)

This error gets fixed if i use this:

```
 public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @EJB (beanName="LocalHelloWorld")
        private HelloWorldInteface localHelloWorld;
    }
```

Why does this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the annotaiton

@Local

is not needed from EJB version 3.1 anymore, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7370053/1925356

Which EJB Version do you use?

Kind regards: Alex

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my version is 3.1.
Will this solve my problem?

Comment: I would try not using the @Local annotation at all. What happens in this case?

Comment: Then, try to use Inject instead of EJB, see here:                                                                            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138232/should-i-use-ejb-or-inject