# Java batch - inject ejb to batchlet

Tags: ejb, cdi, java-batch, jberet, jbatch

I have a startup bean. I want to start some batchlet job in this.
I annotated the batchlet class by use `@Nemed` and `@Dependent` . I want to use some ejb like ReportService in batchlet but Injection not work. How can I inject EJB to my batchlet?
I deployed below example on wildfly 11.0.0.Alpha1 and got empty reference in service object.

BatchletTest:

```
@Dependent
@Named("BatchletTest")
public class BatchletTest extends AbstractBatchlet{


    public BatchletTest() {
    }

    @Inject
    ReportService service;

    @Override
    public String process() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(service);
        return null;
    }
}
```

test-job.xml

```
 <job id="test-job" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="1.0">
        <step id="testStep">
            <batchlet ref="com.test.BatchletTest" />
        </step>
    </job>
```

StartupBean:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
public class StartupBean {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartupBean.class);

    @PostConstruct
    private void startup() throws Exception {
            long executionId = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator().start("test-job", new Properties());
            System.out.println("myJob started, execution ID = " + executionId);

    }

}
```

ReportService:

```
@Stateless
public class ReportService {
.....
}
```

Comment: Which application server and which version?  Any warning and errors in server log?  There should be some CDI injection related warning/erorrs in log.  One possibility is that you're using the FQCN as the bean ref in job xml, which may bypass the CDI loading, which makes the {{service}} injection field out of the reach of CDI.

Comment: I deployed in on wildfly 11.0.0.Alpha1. There was no error in logs.

Comment: Try using the CDI bean name as the batch artifact ref so that CDI can handle the ejb injection into your batchlet class.  <batchlet ref="BatchletTest" />

Answer (score 0):

You are no implementing any interface with @Local anntotaion on your class ReportService.

Try this:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ReportService {
.....
}
```

or

```
@Stateless
public class ReportService implements ReportServiceLocal{
.....
}

@Local
public interface ReportServiceLocal {
.....
}
```

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362257/inject-ejb-local-remote-localbean-etc-confused?rq=1)